# Scaling into a range causes unsymmetrical error.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I need to scale up sine and cosine values to fit to two-compliment bit vector. By using the general formula I am getting an approximation error only near the extrema of the function. It looks like the extreme values are getting more 'squeezed' to fit to the given range. I would like the error to be 'evenly distributed': spread out over all the values, not concentrate near the peaks - putting it differently I would like all the values to be 'pushed' equally. Are there any other formulas I could use?

Generally speaking I am working on a system that uses sine and cosine signals as inputs. I need to test its precision with different bit-widths vectors. To do so, I am generating sin and cosine values in Matlab and then I am scaling their amplitude up to a given bit length. The values need to be represented in the two-compliment form. This means that eg. for a bit length of 12bits I wish to get a vector that ranges between -2047 to 2047, with values evenly distributed throughout this range.
Unfortunately I noticed that there is a scaling error that is concentrated around the maximal values of the function. I have not been able to test my system, because I need to address this issue first.

I am using this formula to scale up my values:
$$
  x' = \frac{(x - min(x))(b - a)}{max(x) - min(x)} + a
$$
and it gives me an asymmetrical error in the desired range.

I calculated the scaling error by simply comparing the values after scaling and rounding, with the original sine/cosine values (in matlab's 16 bit precision). Obviously, due to limited bit-length of the vector I am getting some errors this is expected. Unfortunately these errors can't be treated as noise, they are unevenly distributed. Around the extrema of the functions ($n+\pi/2$ for the sine, and $n\pi$ for the cosine) the biggest error is observed. I don't understand why.

Do you know of any other formulas that would help me get better results? Or is there any other way to deal with the problem?

I am new here, so unfortunately I can't put any graphs that show my results. You can find all the graphs in the link to the original post below.

I also tried to run the Fast Fourier Transformation to check if there is any periodic error that can be addressed. I don't know if I have it done correctly, but I wasn't able to see any periodic component in the error.

The Matlab code for the FFT is given here

```
% sin_12_bit - vector with 3770 sine values saved in 18 bit
Fs = 1000;   %Sampling Frequency
T = 1/Fs;
L = 3770;
t = x;
NFFT  = 2^nextpow2(L);

f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

Y_sin_12_bit = (fft(sin_12bit,NFFT)/L);
Y_sin_18_bit = (fft(sin_18bit,NFFT)/L);
Y_cos_12_bit = (fft(cos_12_bit,NFFT)/L);
Y_cos_18_bit = (fft(cos_18_bit,NFFT)/L);

plot(f,abs(Y_sin_12_bit(1:NFFT/2+1)));
plot(f,abs(Y_sin_18_bit(1:NFFT/2+1)));
plot(f,abs(Y_cos_12_bit(1:NFFT/2+1)));
plot(f,abs(Y_cos_18_bit(1:NFFT/2+1)));
```

Any ideas what to do with this unevenly distributed error?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

(the question  and the graphs have been originally posted in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435212/scaling-into-a-range-causes-unsymmetrical-error )

Comment: You gave code for the FFT, but maybe you should provide code for some example test and the current implementation you are using. Also, it's a bit unclear what you need, are you trying to interpolate a function? Maybe you are trying to create an approximation for a function? Are you trying to fit a curve? Those are all terms that you should research if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have some graphs but I am new, and I can't post them here yet :( Posting the code also makes little sense, as I am using input from a file so the code is useless without the input data. Generally I am using the formula mentioned above.

I am trying to interpolate a sine function, from a given set of values. This gives an error. The interpolation procedure is not error free - the biggest error is near to the extrema of the function. The error is not random. This is a problem for my future analysis of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to the question - it is a typical feature of an uniform quantization error. Values closer to the extremes of the sine function change slower therefor the quantization error is higher in this range. 
Short explanation can be found here: https://dsp-nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/nbsphinx-experiment/quantization/linear_uniform_characteristic.html